# ConcurrentHashMap not inserting the non null key value pair upon calling the put method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap, socketchannel

I am using a ConcurrentHashMap to cache task that I am processing on a SocketChannel. The StreamTask is a Runnable that is use to reschedules itself if the round trip threshold is elapse during client server communication, therefore it will remove itself from the cache if time elapse. Furthermore, StreamWriteTask thread will put it on the cache and the StreaReadTask will attempt to remove it.

The problem is that when I invoke the 'processingCache.put()' it does not always add to the map.

```
public class ClientServerTest {

    private class StreamTask implements Runnable {
        private final String taskIdentifier;
        private byte[] data;
        private int scheduleAttempts = 1;
        private long startTime;
        private Runnable future;

        private static final long ROND_TRIP_THRESHOLD = 15000L;
        private static final int MAX_SCHEDULE_ATTEMPTS = 3;

        public StreamTask(String taskIdentifier, byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.taskIdentifier = taskIdentifier;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (scheduleAttempts < MAX_SCHEDULE_ATTEMPTS) {
                StreamTask task = null;
                processingCacheLock.writeLock().lock(); 
                try{
                    task = processingCache.remove(taskIdentifier);
                }finally{
                    processingCacheLock.writeLock().unlock();
                }

                if (task == null) {
                    return;
                }

                scheduleStreamTask(task);
                scheduleAttempts++;
            } else {
                failedTasks.add(this);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return taskIdentifier == null ? 0 : super.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!(obj instanceof StreamTask)) {
                return false;
            }
            StreamTask task = (StreamTask) obj;
            boolean equals = false;
            if (this.taskIdentifier != null
                    && this.taskIdentifier.equals(task.taskIdentifier)) {
                equals = true;
            }

            if (this.hashCode() == task.hashCode()) {
                equals = true;
            }

            return equals;
        }

    }

    private class StreamWriteTask implements Runnable {
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private SelectionKey key;

        private StreamWriteTask(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.key = key;
        }

        private byte[] getData() {
            byte[] data;
            if (key.attachment() != null) {
                data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
                System.out.println("StreamWriteTask continuation.....");
            } else {
                StreamTask task = getStreamTask();
                if (task == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                System.out.println("Processing New Task ~~~~~ "
                        + task.taskIdentifier);
                processingCacheLock.readLock().lock();
                try {
                    task = processingCache.put(task.taskIdentifier, task);
                    boolean cached = processingCache.containsKey(task.taskIdentifier);
                    System.out.println("Has task been cached? " + cached);
                } finally {
                    processingCacheLock.readLock().unlock();
                }

                task.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                data = task.data;
            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] data = getData();
            if (data != null) {
                SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                buffer.clear();
                buffer.put(data);
                buffer.flip();
                int results = 0;
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    try {
                        results = sc.write(buffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (results == 0) {
                        buffer.compact();
                        buffer.flip();
                        data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                        buffer.get(data);
                        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        key.attach(data);
                        System.out
                                .println("Partial write to socket channel....");
                        selector.wakeup();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out
                    .println("Write to socket channel complete for client...");
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            key.attach(null);
            returnBuffer(buffer);
            selector.wakeup();
        }

    }

    private class StreamReadTask implements Runnable {
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        private SelectionKey key;

        private StreamReadTask(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            buffer.clear();
            byte[] data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
            if (data != null) {
                buffer.put(data);
            }
            int count = 0;
            int readAttempts = 0;
            try {
                while ((count = sc.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    readAttempts++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                buffer.flip();
                data = new byte[buffer.limit()];
                buffer.get(data);
                String uuid = new String(data);
                System.out.println("Client Read - uuid ~~~~ " + uuid);
                boolean success = finalizeStreamTask(uuid, endTime);
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                key.attach(null);
                System.out.println("Did task finalize correctly ~~~~ "
                        + success);
            }

            if (count == -1) {
                try {
                    sc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            returnBuffer(buffer);
            selector.wakeup();
        }

    }

    private class ClientWorker implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (selector.isOpen()) {
                    int count = selector.select(500);

                    if (count == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys()
                            .iterator();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey key = it.next();
                        it.remove();
                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (key.isConnectable()) {
                            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                            if (!sc.finishConnect()) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                        }

                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = borrowBuffer();
                            if (buffer != null) {
                                key.interestOps(0);
                                executor.execute(new StreamReadTask(buffer, key));
                            }
                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = borrowBuffer();
                            if (buffer != null) {
                                key.interestOps(0);
                                executor.execute(new StreamWriteTask(buffer,
                                        key));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Handle Exception
            }

        }
    }

    private class ServerWorker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Selector selector = Selector.open();
                ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                ServerSocket socket = ssc.socket();
                socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9001));
                ssc.configureBlocking(false);
                ssc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(65535);
                DataHandler handler = new DataHandler();

                while (selector.isOpen()) {
                    int count = selector.select(500);

                    if (count == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys()
                            .iterator();

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey key = it.next();
                        it.remove();
                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                            ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                            SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                            sc.configureBlocking(false);
                            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        }
                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            handler.readSocket(buffer, key);
                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            handler.writeToSocket(buffer, key);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class DataHandler {

        private JsonObject parseData(StringBuilder builder) {
            if (!builder.toString().endsWith("}")) {
                return null;
            }

            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(builder.toString());
            return obj;
        }

        private void readSocket(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key)
                throws IOException {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            buffer.clear();
            int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int readAttempts = 0;
            try {
                while ((count = sc.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    readAttempts++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                buffer.flip();
                StringBuilder builder = key.attachment() instanceof StringBuilder ? (StringBuilder) key
                        .attachment() : new StringBuilder();
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode(buffer);
                String content = charBuffer.toString();
                charBuffer = null;
                builder.append(content);
                JsonObject obj = parseData(builder);
                if (obj == null) {
                    // System.out.println("Server processed partial read for task");
                    key.attach(builder);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                } else {
                    JsonPrimitive uuid = obj.get("uuid").getAsJsonPrimitive();
                    System.out
                            .println("Server read complete for task  ~~~~~~~ "
                                    + uuid);
                    key.attach(uuid.toString().getBytes());
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                }
            }

            if (count == -1) {
                key.attach(null);
                sc.close();
            }
        }

        private void writeToSocket(ByteBuffer buffer, SelectionKey key)
                throws IOException {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
            byte[] data = (byte[]) key.attachment();
            buffer.clear();
            buffer.put(data);
            buffer.flip();
            int writeAttempts = 0;
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                int results = sc.write(buffer);
                writeAttempts++;
                // System.out.println("Write Attempt #" + writeAttempts);
                if (results == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Server process partial write....");
                    buffer.compact();
                    buffer.flip();
                    data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(data);
                    key.attach(data);
                    key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                    return;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Server write complete for task ~~~~~ "
                    + new String(data));
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            key.attach(null);
        }
    }

    public ClientServerTest() throws IOException {
        selector = Selector.open();
        processingCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, StreamTask>(
                MAX_DATA_LOAD, 2);
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_DATA_LOAD; index++) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            obj.addProperty("uuid", uuid);
            String data = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(12800000);
            obj.addProperty("event", data);
            StreamTask task = new StreamTask(uuid, obj.toString().getBytes());
            taskQueue.add(task);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < CLIENT_SOCKET_CONNECTIONS; index++) {
            ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 << 23);
            bufferQueue.add(bf);
            SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9001));
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
        }

        Thread serverWorker = new Thread(new ServerWorker());
        serverWorker.start();

        Thread clientWorker = new Thread(new ClientWorker());
        clientWorker.start();

    }

    private void start() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (;;) {
            if (taskQueue.isEmpty() && processingCache.isEmpty()) {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Overall Processing time ~~~~ "
                        + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private ByteBuffer borrowBuffer() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = null;

        try {
            buffer = bufferQueue.poll(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer;
    }

    private boolean returnBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        boolean success = true;
        try {
            buffer.clear();
            bufferQueue.offer(buffer, 5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            success = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }

    private StreamTask getStreamTask() {
        StreamTask task = null;
        taskQueueAddLock.lock();
        try {
            task = taskQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            taskQueueAddLock.unlock();
        }

        return task;
    }

    private boolean scheduleStreamTask(StreamTask task) {
        boolean success = true;
        taskQueueRemoveLock.lock();
        try {
            taskQueue.offer(task, 5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            success = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            taskQueueRemoveLock.unlock();
        }

        return success;
    }

    private boolean finalizeStreamTask(String uuid, long endTime) {
        boolean success = true;
        StreamTask task;
        processingCacheLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            task = processingCache.remove(uuid);
            success = task != null;
        } finally {
            processingCacheLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }

        if (success) {
            success = executor.remove(task.future);
            executor.purge();
        }

        if (!success) {
            taskQueueAddLock.lock();
            taskQueueRemoveLock.lock();
            try {
                Iterator<StreamTask> it = taskQueue.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    task = it.next();
                    if (task.taskIdentifier == uuid) {
                        it.remove();
                        success = true;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                taskQueueAddLock.unlock();
                taskQueueRemoveLock.unlock();
            }
            success = !taskQueue.contains(task);
        }

        System.out.println("Processing time ~~~~~~ "
                + (endTime - task.startTime) + "ms");
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClientServerTest test = new ClientServerTest();
            test.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final int CLIENT_SOCKET_CONNECTIONS = 1;
    private static final int MAX_DATA_LOAD = 2;

    private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, StreamTask> processingCache;
    private volatile LinkedBlockingQueue<StreamTask> taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<StreamTask>();
    private volatile ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(
            CLIENT_SOCKET_CONNECTIONS);
    private volatile LinkedBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> bufferQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>();
    private volatile List<StreamTask> failedTasks = new ArrayList<StreamTask>();
    private volatile Selector selector;
    private final ReentrantLock taskQueueAddLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final ReentrantLock taskQueueRemoveLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock processingCacheLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
}
```

Comment: so, if you're using a ConcurrentHashMap, why are you synchronizing access to it, and why is it volatile?

Comment: There is far, far too much code posted here for us to help.  See here: http://sscce.org/

Comment: If you are implying that there is a bug in `ConcurrentHashMap` then I assure you that most likely there is a bug in your logic.  I would use a debugger or `println` debugging to see why the `put` method is not being called or to make sure that it is putting the values that you expect.

Comment: @Gray -I am not implying anything. I am more asking for suggestions and constructive help. I have debug the code and it is being called, but it seems it is putting the key value pair in, but being erased after the synchronization block. I have realized that synchronizing on that object will not achieve what I want, but the behavior in question is interesting.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek As for why I am using the concurrenthashmap, In the case I have multiple thread adding to the cache I do not want them to wait on each other, but when a read thread removing from the cache, I need all threads that are adding to block until the remove is finish. Now that I thinking about it maybe I should use the ReadWritedReentrant lock for this

Comment: I have tried the following: I switch to using a regular HashMap without any synchronization; it did not work. I have tried not having the StreamTask implement the Runnable interface; it did not work. I have even tried storing a arbitrary String value instead of the StreamTask object.

Comment: Sorry dude.  Just not enough information for me to help.  Your post says "processingCache.put()' it does not always add to the map".  I am just saying that if you are calling `put()` it is being added to the map.  Maybe it's not adding what you expect or maybe it is being removed by another thread but your post seems to indicate that the put() didn't work.  Sorry if I'm misreading.

Comment: @Gray - So I posted all of the code just in case someone wants to copy and paste the code to debug it, but in the StreamWriterTask.getData() method I invoke the processingCache.put method and step to the next line; I can see the StreamTask and Key are in the map, but as soon as I step to the next line the map is cleared. There is only one thread in the ExecutorThreadPool, so only one Runnable can process at a time.

Comment: Actually, I'm suggesting that you stick with ConcurrentHashMap, which is thread-safe (hence the name), remove all of your synchronization code, which I believe to be unnecessary, and remove all use of the 'volatile' keyword, which may well be the source of your problem.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek -Yea, I tried everything you stated above before (throwing logic out the window). I believe for the problem I am trying solve my synchronization is not the problem. The volatile keyword is not the issue; the volatile keyword just tells the jvm to make all changes directly to the main memory address at the time of access.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably a misunderstanding of what `put()` returns. After this line:

```
task = processingCache.put(task.taskIdentifier, task);
```

task is equal to the previous value stored in the map for that key if any or null otherwise. If the map did not have a key `task.taskIdentifier` before that call, then `put()` returns null and the next line:

```
boolean cached = processingCache.containsKey(task.taskIdentifier);
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`.

From [ConcurrenMap#put javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the **previous** value associated with key, or **null** if there was no mapping for key

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. However, I was evaluating the contains(key) and isEmpty method.  So for example, if I invoked put() on line 100, and stepped(debugger), to line 101 it would evaluate correctly, but when I step to line 102  those expression evaluates incorrectly; that is contains(key)=false and isEmpty() = true.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you - but you should follow the advice given by Gray: create a SSCCE that replicates the issue by removing as much unnecessary stuff as possible while still seeing the issue. That should help you better understand what is going on.

Comment: I have already concluded that threading is not the problem. I believe this something related to the CocurrentHashMap,but the code works fine.